# Unknown Svn error

Tags: svn

I'm suddenly getting this error from SVN:

```
svn: E155009: Failed to run the WC DB work queue associated with
'/homepages/46/d548322256/htdocs/dev2/dev/js/phpguru', work item 1097 (file-
install 6 ?\195?\163?\194?\133?\194?\135 1 0 1 1)
svn: E000022: Can't convert string from 'UTF-8' to native encoding:
svn: E000022: /homepages/46/d548322256/htdocs/dev2/dev/?\195?\163?\194?\133?
\194?\135
```

Anyone know what it means?

Comment: What command do you run to get this error? What Subversion client do you use?

Comment: Its version 1.8.10 and this is from the command line client. Oh, its on 1and1 too if that helps